# How can I reference a script object within a html <div>?

Tags: javascript, html

I created a script object in my index.html file. It is supposed to display my game board with the `<div>` but instead there is nothing there. I have tried multiple things and this is the last thing I tried.

```
      <script type = "text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready( function() ){
            var game = Sudoku.getInstance();
            $('#container').append( game.getGameBoard() );
            $('#validate').click( function(){
                game.validate();
            } );
            $('#reset').click( function(){
                game.reset();
            });
        } );
      </script>
      <h2>  Sudoku Game Online </h2>
        <div id = "container"> 
            <script type = "text/javascript">
            $( document ).ready( function() ){
                var game = Sudoku.getInstance();
                $document.getElementById("container").innerHTML= ( game.getGameBoard() );
            </script>
        </div>
```

but the following is what I started with. problem is that the page is loading but container  is not displaying the grid or anything in it.

```
   <script type = "text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready( function() ){
            var game = Sudoku.getInstance();
            $('#container').append( game.getGameBoard() );
            $('#validate').click( function(){
                game.validate();
            } );
            $('#reset').click( function(){
                game.reset();
            });
        } );
        </script>

        <h2>  Sudoku Game Online </h2>
        <div id = "container"> </div>
```

Comment: Maybe this `$document` is a typo in the line?$document.getElementById("container").innerHTML

Comment: Make sure that you're including jQuery on the page (I'm unsure since the full source isn't included in your question). But @AnthonyC 's suggestion is also correct, it should be `document.getElementById(...`

Comment: @EvanDarwin you too. and jQuery is included as well.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages in the console? If so what are they? What have you tried? [mcve].